# Is there a way to print java class fields by netbeans code templates?

Tags: java, netbeans, syntax

For example class:

```
public class JavaClassExample{
   private String field_1;
   public String field_2;
   public int field_3;
}
```

What the code template to get:

```
System.out.println(field_1 + " " + field_2 + " " + field_3);
```

I also can use it to make my own toString() generator

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JavaClassExample c = new JavaClassExample();//create an instance of your class
        System.out.println(c.field_2 + " " + c.field_2 
                + " " + c.field_3);//call the fields
    }
}
```

You can also use [encapsulation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm) using getters and setters :

```
System.out.println(c.getField_1() + " " + c.getField_2() + " " + c.getField_3());
```

Or you can use `toString` :

```
public class JavaClassExample {

    private String field_1;
    private String field_2;
    private int field_3;

    //...getters and setters

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return field_2 + " " + field_2 + " " + field_3;
    }

}
```

So you can print your object using just :

```
System.out.println(c);
```